# Grouping timeseries with same time stamp

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, pandas-groupby

fairly new to Pandas and starting to get a grasp of the concept. Hopefully, you can point me in the right direction.

I a dataset of measured temperature values of the following structure. The dataset is around 1-2 millions entries long. As some sensors failed at some point I have quite a bit of missing data present.

```
                          location  temperature
timestamp                                      
2019-08-22 21:28:56         Garage        23.54
2019-08-22 21:29:44        bedroom        23.33
2019-08-23 22:21:06       outside1        25.00
2019-08-23 22:21:33       outside2        24.12
2019-08-22 21:29:53         Garage        23.40
[...]
```

What I would like to do is to resample the dataset in such a way, as that the timestamps of the individual sensors line up. **Specifically, I would like to be able to calculate means/differences of various sensors.** How can I do this?

Overall, I am not sure what the best approach would be to represent such data to make it easy to work with. I am aware of creating groups, which already is a great start. But I still don't know how I could create those calculations between sensors in a simple way.

Any help would be really much appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: Do you want to group data in such a way that you have a mean for every hour for each location or something of this kind ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best approach would be to pivot the dataframe first so you have a time series column for each sensor:

```
df.pivot(columns="location", values="temperature")                                                                                        

location             Garage  bedroom  outside1  outside2
timestamp                                               
2019-08-22 21:28:56   23.54      NaN       NaN       NaN
2019-08-22 21:29:44     NaN    23.33       NaN       NaN
2019-08-22 21:29:53   23.40      NaN       NaN       NaN
2019-08-23 22:21:06     NaN      NaN      25.0       NaN
2019-08-23 22:21:33     NaN      NaN       NaN     24.12
```

Then you could fill the missing data with an interpolation

```
df.pivot(columns="location", values="temperature").interpolate(method="time", limit_direction="both")                                     

location                Garage  bedroom  outside1  outside2
timestamp                                                  
2019-08-22 21:28:56  23.540000    23.33      25.0     24.12
2019-08-22 21:29:44  23.422105    23.33      25.0     24.12
2019-08-22 21:29:53  23.400000    23.33      25.0     24.12
2019-08-23 22:21:06  23.400000    23.33      25.0     24.12
2019-08-23 22:21:33  23.400000    23.33      25.0     24.12
```

Now you should have all data points temporally aligned, you could maybe resample to a constant sampling rate, let's say "1 min"

```
df.pivot(columns="location", values="temperature").interpolate(method="time", limit_direction="both").resample("1 min").mean()            

location                Garage  bedroom  outside1  outside2
timestamp                                                  
2019-08-22 21:28:00  23.540000    23.33      25.0     24.12
2019-08-22 21:29:00  23.411053    23.33      25.0     24.12
2019-08-22 21:30:00        NaN      NaN       NaN       NaN
2019-08-22 21:31:00        NaN      NaN       NaN       NaN
2019-08-22 21:32:00        NaN      NaN       NaN       NaN
...                        ...      ...       ...       ...
2019-08-23 22:17:00        NaN      NaN       NaN       NaN
2019-08-23 22:18:00        NaN      NaN       NaN       NaN
2019-08-23 22:19:00        NaN      NaN       NaN       NaN
2019-08-23 22:20:00        NaN      NaN       NaN       NaN
2019-08-23 22:21:00  23.400000    23.33      25.0     24.12
```

You obviously have a lot of missing data with such a small sampling interval and sparse data points, I guess you have more in your actual dataset (ideally you want at least one data point in each resampled interval).

Now it's up to you and your actual data to decide how to proceed. You could fill the missing data using `.nearest()` instead of `.mean()`. If the missing items are just a few, you could fill them with the rolling mean.

Comment: Hey - sorry it took a while to answer (that happens with hobby projects..) Your code really  works like a charm and does what I need! One point I did not mention in my original question is that apart from temperature I also measured humidity and dew point. Is there a way for a 3D type pivot table? Otherwise I might just create three individual pivot tables.

Comment: Also - your assumption was correct - I have data from each sensor each minute, my overall dataset is close to 2 million datasets (home temperature monitoring system)